# Unable to identify clickable element using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape search results from Bing.com for practice purposes. I am unable to identify the correct button to click to move to the next page.

The button lies in `li` list which contains

`<a class="sb_pagN sb_pagN_bp b_widePag sb_bp " title="Next page" href="/search?q=site%3alinkedin.com%2fin%2f+AND+%22Harvard-business-school%22+AND+%22MBA%22&amp;sp=-1&amp;pq=&amp;sc=0-0&amp;qs=n&amp;sk=&amp;cvid=A37699D61CB9427F836AB76C607801CD&amp;first=7&amp;FORM=PORE" h="ID=SERP,5423.1"><div class="sw_next">Next</div></a>`

and I am unable to click on it using class name and even other attrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why class name, why not `link_text` ?

```
find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
```

should work in that Next element is in Selenium view port.

I think you probably will have to scroll down since Next buttons are always at the end of a web page.

incase if that is required scroll down like this  :

```
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Harvard-business-school%22+AND+%22MBA%22&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=&sc=0-0&qs=n&sk=&cvid=A37699D61CB9427F836AB76C607801CD")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.execute_script("var scrollingElement = (document.scrollingElement || document.body);scrollingElement.scrollTop = scrollingElement.scrollHeight;")
sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Next']/.."))).click()
```

**Imports  :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Hey I already tried that! it gives me ```NoSuchElementException    ```

Comment: Can you share the website url ?

Comment: sure, it's ```https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alinkedin.com%2Fin%2F+AND+%22Harvard-business-school%22+AND+%22MBA%22&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=&sc=0-0&qs=n&sk=&cvid=A37699D61CB9427F836AB76C607801CD```

Comment: The next button is not available, I could not found one

Comment: Exactly, at the bottom of the page, there is an arrow! and series of page numbers

Comment: You just want to click on that  ?

Comment: Yes, because that will redirect me to the next page

Comment: Sure mate, Check out the update 1 code above.

Comment: No issue bro. Keep rocking

Comment: https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3alinkedin.com%2fin%2f+AND+%22Harvard-business-school%22+AND+%22MBA%22&sp=-1&pq=&sc=0-0&qs=n&sk=&cvid=501A2EE5DB644AD1B61F60F3D56630A4&first=941&FORM=PORE

this is the link to 95/97th page and post 100, it just loops bw 96-101